# Short toc : tight option not working

Tags: spacing, shorttoc

I'm using the package shorttoc to get a summary at the begining of my document (the toc is at the end). 
For the document is very long (a thesis) I want to reduce the vertical space between the items in the summary.
Though the "tight" option is done for that kind of use, it's not working for me : the vertical space is still the same...

Here his a minimal code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}

\begin{document}
\shorttoc{Summary}{0}

\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\section{anoter section}
\chapter{another chapter}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

The result is exactly the same as with the command \usepackage[loose]{shorttoc} ! Any idea to correct this ?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is not very explicit about the options; after examining the package code, it is apparent that `tight` and `loose` can't give different results, because the `tight` option sets the parameter `\parsep` to zero when typesetting the short table of contents. But `\parsep` is *not* relevant in that context: it is only in `list` based environments, and the table of contents doesn't qualify as a `list` based environment.